# Want to Block Notification in a iOS App when the device is in lock state using Firebase?

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase, service

I have developed a chat App in Android using Firebase which has the concept of blocking push notification when my device is in lock condition. For this feature, I required to implement Foreground service because as soon as the user unlocks his device, the device receives the blocked notifications or all the blocked chat messages.

Now, I want to develop the iOS version of this App using the same Firebase but I'm not sure if I can hold the notification like the Android if my iOS device is in lock condition (with App not running in the background). So, is this feature is feasible in iOS and if yes then how I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From my research, you used to be able to register for a specific Darwin notification, `com.apple.springboard.lockstate` . However, Apple is rejecting apps for this practice as the API is not public.

If you could explain why you’re attempting to catch notifications while the device is locked.

A thought: perhaps a silent push could be of benefit.

Comment: Hey, thanks for sharing this vital information. Actually, the concept of Chat App is like the user should not be notified about the messages until he's actively using his cell phone. This will prevent them from distracting. 

Regarding the silent push code, I had a thought about it but even using this, I guess, I won't be able to catch the flashing of push notification in the lock screen. Right ?

You know Android OS is flexible and I was able to block/catch the notification, which means, I also managed to hold/catch the flashing of Notification in the lock screen.